# Dynamic EMF Model

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, emf

I'm looking at creating a model that can be enhanced with additional plugins.  The core model would only introduce some fairly fundamental types.  For example an asset management system could define a basic model in plugin A that would define assets, suppliers etc.  An additional plugin B would add a number of specializations for computer equipment and another plugin C would bring in specializations for something else.

I'd like my application to have a single model, with plugin B and C creating their specialized instances and adding them to the model in residing in plugin A. Is this possible, all the documentation I can find seems concerned with extending a model but creating an instance of that, not mixing and matching.  If it matters, objects would only be created in the plugin that defines that type.

Additionally I'd like other plugins to enrich the data model, e.g. a fault management plugin D could add data to the objects to hold fault status.

Is this achievable with EMF?

I had thought that if it is not possible to do this directly that I could possibly achieve the required result by chaining the model objects by having them implementing IAdpatable, but having a single model seems better.